# Best practice for creating SQL SELECT queries while handling potential undefined values

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I'm currently creating a NodeJS website using PostgreSQL via [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

I have a page with an HTML form with checkboxes to select variables to search the database for using various fields. These are then fed into a SQL query with `pg-promise` and the intended behaviour is the results are passed back to the user in JSON format.

A very minimal working example would be as follows.

HTML form:

```
<form action="/search" method="get">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Variable A</legend>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="variable_a" value="apple">
                <label for="variable_a">
                    Apple
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="variable_a" value="orange">
                <label for="variable_a">
                    Orange
                </label>
            </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Variable B</legend>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="variable_b" value="pear">
                <label for="variable_b">
                    Pear
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="variable_b" value="banana">
                <label for="variable_b">
                    Banana
                </label>
            </div>
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

From this an URL like the following is created `/search?variable_b=pear&variable_b=banana`

The problem I have is when trying to create a 'catch all' SQL SELECT query to handle this search.

This is the SQL query I have created in `pg-promise`:

```
router.get('/search', function(req, res, next) {
    db.any(`SELECT * FROM food 
            WHERE variable_a IN ($1:csv)
            AND variable_b IN ($2:csv)`, [req.query.variable_a, req.query.variable_b])
        .then(result=>res.send(result))
        .catch();
});
```

This fails given the `/search?variable_b=pear&variable_b=banana` URL, but works with say the following URL `/search?variable_a=apple&variable_b=banana`.

This is undoubtedly because in the example above `req.query.variable_a` is undefined as no checkboxes were selected and the SQL query falls over with `IN ()`. I should perhaps add, if `variable_a` or `variable_b` isn't defined by a checkbox, in this case the intended behaviour is there is no filter on said columns.

My question is what is the best way of handling this?

I feel like I could probably create a lot of if/else logic to handle potential undefined `req.query` variables and resulting SQL queries but this seems messy and not elegant.

Comment: I don't quite understand why the first query would fail. However, it sounds like you need to build a method to dynamically build the query & parameters. Or possibly better would be to make a stored procedure that accepts a parameter list of your variables then build the query dynamically there based on the parameter list.

Comment: I believe it fails because it potentially evaluates to `SELECT * FROM food  WHERE variable_a IN () AND variable_b IN ('pear', 'banana');` and this returns `ERROR: syntax error at or near ')'` which I believe is referring to the empty `IN` parens.

Comment: Oh I see now, are those valid inputs? If not, maybe use a combobox instead of checkbox?

Comment: In this case it is a valid input. A user can search the database with checkbox defined variable filter(s) on `variable_a` and/or `variable_b` or none at all or anything inbetween.

Comment: The same issue as here: https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/issues/442

Comment: @vitaly-t yep, I don't think it's a problem with `pg-promise` itself, I'm more curious as to an elegant solution to empty `IN ()`.

Comment: See my answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is the same as was logged here: https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/issues/442

Basically, [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) query formatting engine generates SQL according to your formatting parameters. It does NOT do any syntax verification on your resulting SQL.

You are generating `IN ()`, which is invalid SQL, so you get the error.

You should check for the presence of the variable, and not even try to generate such a query when the variable is missing, because your query wouldn't be able to yield anything good then.

**Example:**

```
router.get('/search', (req, res, next) => {
    const variables = ['variable_a', 'variable_b', 'variable_c'];
    const conditions = variables.filter(v => v in req.query)
        .map(v => pgp.as.format('$1:name IN ($2:csv)', [v, req.query[v]]))
        .join(' AND ');

    conditions = conditions && 'WHERE ' + conditions;

    db.any('SELECT * FROM food $1:raw', conditions)
        .then(result => res.send(result))
        .catch(error => {/* handle the error */});
});
```

There can be other solutions, as [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) is very generic, it does not limit you the way you approach this.

For example, instead of this:

```
v => pgp.as.format('$1:name IN ($2:csv)', [v, req.query[v]])
```

you can do this:

```
v => pgp.as.name(v) + ' IN (' + pgp.as.csv(req.query[v]) + ')';
```

which will produce the same result. Whichever you like! ;)

Comment: Thanks, I like this. No ugly logic, it's nice and concise.

Comment: @BML91 I did a few improvements, to use `:name` filter for the column name: https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#sql-names

Comment: Thanks. I think the `variables.map()` needs a `.filter(v => v !== null)` before the `.join()` otherwise you seem to get things like `variable_a IN ('apple') AND AND AND` for the not present variables.

Comment: @BML91 Now the example is even better, to show the best approach to executing a non-conditional query when there are no conditions.

Answer (score 0):

first - your input will keep **only** last selected value

```
<input type="checkbox" name="variable_a" value="apple">
```

or you should use name with [] to inform that its an array

second - you can use **?** statement just inside params or var

```
req.query.variable_a ? req.query.variable_a : null
```

And inside your SQL - if you didnt send any of vars - you want get result
cause its strict AND statement - var undefined - the query return false

Comment: The checkboxes work as expected - for example if both boxes are checked for `variable_b` the URL is `/search?variable_b=pear&variable_b=banana`  and both variables can be accessed via `req.params.variable_b` in an array. The second part of your answer I can't understand how you would implement in this situation.