# How to do SQL query filtering when certain params are not passed in?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, go, sqlx

I've built a REST endpoint for listing items, `/api/items`, and it can be passed a few options via query params for filtering the result.

For example, `GET /api/items?minPrice=30&maxPrice=100&minRating=4&onSale=true`

How can I translate this into my SQL queries?

If I get a request with only `maxPrice=50`, then what about the other parameters?  Let's just assume the following is my query -

```
select * from items 
where minPrice=(???) and maxPrice=50 and minRating=(???) and onSale=(???)
```

How do I "ignore" a filter if nothing was requested for it, and only filter on `maxPrice=50`?  Is there a programmatic way to do this?

In my case, I am using postgres, so I have paramterized query with `&1`, `&2`, etc. with the values for each one.

Comment: I'm from the C# world, and there you typically use a data layer which allows you to add optional parameters to SQL statements. It may not help directly, but may trigger a thought how to solve this in your world plus it eliminates risks of SQL injection.

Comment: are you using express js ?

Comment: I'm using Go + sqlx, porting an app that was half way written in node+express using knex

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: The same problem solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48344888/best-practice-for-creating-sql-select-queries-while-handling-potential-undefined

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose You need to write a custom query for any kind of condition.

Usually ORM tools do great jobs:

In case of Java (Spring and JPA) you can use criteria api and some helpers, one of which is Spring Data's builder pattern for specifications:

```
Specifications fullSpec = null;
if (param1 != null) {
    fullSpec = Specifications.where(<... criteria condition for param1 ...>);
}

if (param2 != null) { 
    if (fullSpec != null) {
        specs = fullSpec.and(<define condition using criteria api>);
    } else {
        fullSpec = Specifications.where(<same condition for param2>);
    }
}
```

While you are on NodeJS (seems to be true from tags) you can use [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com). Straight from its tutorials:

```
var filterObject = {
    minValue: <its value received from request>, 
    maxValue: <its value received from request>, 
    minRating: <its value received from request>, 
    maxRating: <its value received from request>
  };

// filterout null valued properties out of filter
filterObject = _.compactObject(filterObject);

Items.findAll({
  where: filterObject
});
```

And that's all you need to achieve your results  in a safe manner.

This example uses underscore mixin for filtering-out null values from object as it was shown in [This response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058193/remove-empty-properties-falsy-values-from-object-with-underscore-js)

Also you can always write your query following way:

```
var query = 'select * from items where maxPrice=:maxPrice'
if (minPrice) {
    query = query + ' and minPrice=:minPrice'
}
//...
// fill-in all other conditions.
//...
// and then simply query with named parameters.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide meaningful default values, if the values are not provided in the REST call. e.g.

```
minValue = 0 
maxValue = <veryHighValue>
minRating = 0
onSale in (true, false)
```

Or you can start with these default values, and override then with the ones provided from the REST call.